# What field name would throw a JSONParsing Exception in Java?

Tags: java, json, rest

I want to cause a parsing exception while processing a REST request.

Is it possible to do or any other suggestions ?

Comment: Just send up junk?

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion 1: just throw a `JSONParsingException` instead of parsing the request.  For example, using a mock request parser.

Suggestion 2: pass an invalid request; e.g. one which does not conform to the JSON syntax.  For example, modify a valid JSON request by replacing a field / attribute name with an integer.